# How to change the input after text color

Tags: html, css, input

I have an input type text,and i've changed its background-color in grey,but when I am writing something in the field, the grey background-color changes to a yellow one, I think that's its default color.

Is there any code for fixing this ?

Comment: Not sure. It should work. http://jsfiddle.net/gg2x8heo/

Comment: that's not what i meant,i dont want to change the text color,but the field color.I already find teh answer thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is something that was saved inside the browser. The background of yellow color indicated the saved form data.

You can remove the saved form data from the Browser settings. There is no way to control it, but by browser itself. :)

Comment: thanks,i just wanted to know why,and if i can fix it.It wasn't necesary to downvote the question even if it was misspelled,i was in a hurry

Comment: @PetruLebada, I didn't downvote your question brother :) I just editted it to make it a better fit. However, I have answered your question that you just can't fix it. :)

Comment: yeah but it seems like your edit gave me -2

Comment: @PetruLebada, actually even if I remove the edit it will be -2, because 2 people downvoted your question. Editing doesn't give a negative result. :)